# Unable to get Web Search to work in Google TV Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-tv

I'm unable to browse the web through the Google TV Emulator using the pre-installed search application. I'm running the emulator through the Eclipse plugin on Ubuntu 11.1 (KVM enabled). Everything except for the search functionality is running smoothly.

I have enabled "Web" as a searchable item from the System Settings, but when I perform a search on "www.Google.com," for instance, I get the error:

"The application Search (process com.android.quicksearchbox) has stopped unexpectedly.   Please try again."

According to the Application Manager, the service is running. When I search for an application like "clock" through the search application, it works fine.

I tried to debug this issue by running the emulator with verbose and debug flags, but I don't get any additional error information. There is no problem with my internet. I can browse the web outside of the emulator, and I'm able to register my Google Account from within the emulator so there is at least some network functionality. I tried installing a few browsers like Opera in the emulator, but they don't work either.

Is anyone experiencing this issue, or have any ideas what might be causing this?

Thanks,

-Dylan

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this might be an issue with the web search provider.  Since Chrome isn't available on the emulator, domain name searches might cause problems.  Could you perform a few global searches with other domains and see if you get the same failure?

In any event, please file a bug at and we'll look into it:

http://code.google.com/p/googletv-issues/